# Laravel model - return null if the DB table doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

When I create a model, I want to check if the table exists in the DB. If it doesn't then I want to return a null. This is to prevent a record insert if the table doesn't exist yet.

In my model I have tried this. The Schema call returns false, but I'm still getting a model returned and not a null.

```
class SomeDataTable extends Model
{
  public function __construct($id)
  {
    $this->setTable($id);
    if (Schema::connection($this->connection)->hasTable($this->table) === false) {
      return null;
    }else{
      parent::__construct();
    }
  }

  public function setTable($id)
  {
    $this->table = $id.'_some_data_table';
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not a correct way to do this. You have to have table for model.

Comment: Right, that's why I'm trying to check if the table exists before I create a model.

Comment: if you are creating Model class you have to have table for it. i`m trying to thing tha reason why model may not have table

Comment: you cannot return `null` in constructor, constructor is used to initialize the object and its properties by assigning. When you want a object to become nullable. that means you want to destroying the object or clean up resources.

Comment: "This is to prevent a record insert if the table doesn't exist yet." Record definitely can't be inserted if table doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're looking for an ubiquitous solution. But what I'd do is do `php aritsan migrate -m` in the terminal to run migrations of all models. That way, all model tables are created by default.